# OutOfMemory Error : GC overhead limit exceeded - Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am using hibernate to save data to my table.
I have my entity class and main class, through main class i have called the entity class constructor and build the object and in a for loop saving the object to DB through hibernate. I am getting OutofMemory Error : GC overhead limit exceeded, I dont understand why, Can anyone please help?
[OutOfMemoryError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi2sv.png)

Here's my code :

```
Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
for(int i=0;i<serviceIds.length;i=i++)
{
 EntityClass ec = new EntityClass
                            (Integer.parseInt(serviceIds[i]),0,someId3, 0,1,id2,
                            new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), 0,
                            null, null, 0, null,null,null,null);
session.save(ec);
}
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

Here's my entity class:

```
public class EntityClass implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private Integer someId1;
    private Integer someId2;
    private Integer someId3;
    private Integer flag1;
    private Integer flag2;
    private Integer createdBy;
    private Timestamp createdDate;
    private Integer modifiedBy;
    private Timestamp modifiedDate;
    private Timestamp endDate;
    private Integer attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
    private String attribute3;
    private String attribute4;
    private String attribute5;
//full constructor
public EntityClass(Integer someId1, Integer someId2,
            Integer someId3, Integer funBlockFlag, Integer functionalFlag,
            Integer createdBy, Timestamp createdDate, Integer modifiedBy,
            Timestamp modifiedDate, Timestamp endDate, Integer attribute1,
            String attribute2, String attribute3, String attribute4,
            String attribute5) {
        this.someId1= someId1;
        this.someId2 = someId2;
        this.someId3 = someId3;
        this.funBlockFlag = funBlockFlag;
        this.functionalFlag = functionalFlag;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
        this.attribute3 = attribute3;
        this.attribute4 = attribute4;
        this.attribute5 = attribute5;
    }
//getter and setters of all fields
```

Can anyone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When we persist an entity (in this case `EntityClass`), Hibernate will store it in the persistence context.

From your case, it seem like the length for serviceIds might be too large with the memory that you set for your JVM.

Perhaps try to flush and clear the persistence context for every N elements. For example, let said your BATCH_SIZE is 20

```
private static final BATCH_SIZE = 20; // declare at class level

Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
for(int i=0;i<serviceIds.length;i=i++)
{
    EntityClass ec = new EntityClass
                            (Integer.parseInt(serviceIds[i]),0,someId3, 0,1,id2,
                            new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), 0,
                            null, null, 0, null,null,null,null);
    session.save(ec);

    if (i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

Comment: serviceIds length is 3 only @MK Tan, also error is coming on session.save(ec) line

Comment: @SearchingForSolutions If that is the case then based on the give code snippet, I can't determine whether it is caused by Hibernate, it could be other running threads that caused the GC can't claim the free memory. What is the max heap that you set and in what environment that you run this code?